# Change chart colors

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart/histogram, all working fine.
I need to change the text and lines on the chart is on a black background.I
Also, the bar colors need to be orange.
I have had a look around the web, and seen some references to .attr("style":...); and have tried this without success.
Any pointers gratefully received.

```
<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 1890 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the data
d3.json("/assets/js/risk_hist_values.json", function(error, data) {
    // the number of columns in this chart
    var numCols = data.length;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Letter = d.bin_no;
        d.Freq = +d.count;
    });

  // scale the range of the data
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Freq; })]);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Count:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.count + "</span>";
  })


// call the tips
svg.call(tip);

  // add axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Count");


  // Add bar chart
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Freq); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
      .on('click', drill)
      .attr("id", function(d, i){ return 'b_'+i+''; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Freq); });

});

function drill(){
    alert( 'drilling' );
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle.

Comment: Where is your D3 code?

Comment: My apologies.. D3 code is now in place.